# Log4j logs not rolling on size constraint when server is up

Tags: log4j

I i am using log4j1.2.16 with log4j extras for rolling log files based on size. The problem i am facing is the logs are not rolled over at all irrespective of the size constraint when server is up and running. Though the logs are rolled over when the server is restarted based on log file sizes. Refer below for the code snippet of the log4j configuration xml:

```
    <appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE" />        
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>             
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy" >      
        <param name="ActiveFileName" value="C:/File.log" /> 
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="C:/%i.File_%d{dd-MMM-yyyy}.log.zip"/>

    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5000000" />
    </triggeringPolicy>         
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-12d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%t] [%-5p] %C %M [Line number:%L]  %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```